# How to track the number of prints using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, browser, printjs

If I use [Print.js](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) library to print my div like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="document-editor" runat="server">
        <div class="document-editor__toolbar"></div>
        <div class="document-editor__editable-container">
            <div class="document-editor__editable" id="editor1" runat="server">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="printJS({
    printable: 'ContentPlaceHolder1_editor1', type: 'html', css: ['CSS/StatementVerifacation.css'], scanStyles:false})" value="Print" />

    <script>
        DecoupledEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('.document-editor__editable'), {

            })
            .then(editor => {
                window.editor = editor;
                $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_editor1").addClass("disabledbutton");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
</asp:Content>
```

---

I want to track `the number of prints`,

My question is how to disable the browser printing dialog to count the number of prints through counting the number of clicks on **my print button**,or at least track the number of printing copies in the browser printing dialog window?

Comment: Are you trying to count how many times someone clicks the print button? I'm not sure if you can disable the browser printing since it's built in

Comment: @Keith : I want to track the number of prints, so If i count the number of click on my print button, It will be not accurate, because the user may change the number of copies in the browser printing dialog window, so I want to print directly without this window or try to count the number of copies in the dialog window?

Comment: JavaScript has no access to that data

Comment: @epascarello and i can't print diretly without this dialog window?

Comment: could you imagine going to a site and it would just start printing?

Comment: @epascarello Should I do this task in windows app ?